# Line Height Seemingly Not Respecting Div on Large Font on Chrome

Tags: html, css

I'm stuck trying to figure out why on this site (http://areyouafuckingidiot.com/) the very large "No" in the middle, seems to overlap other divs. You can see this when you inspect the "No!" text, and add 'border-bottom: solid 1px darkblue' to .statement-text, you can see how it overlaps the next element down. (set aside for the moment why I'm using anchor tags, that's coming later).

However, when I try to replicate in a simple fiddle, I'm not able to. Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aronchick/uXH9C/5/ and a simple reduction to what I'm doing.

```
<div id="firstDiv" class="normalSized"><a href="#" class="normalLink">Great text in here</a></div>
<div id="secondDiv" class="veryLarge"><a href="#" class="LargeLink">VERY LARGE</a></div>
<div id="thirdDiv" class="normalSized"><a href="#" class="normalLink">Back to Normal</a></div>
```

The middle div is properly spaced and does not overlap. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your fiddle doesn't have the same styles as the page. Here's an [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uXH9C/7/) with the same styles and obviously we find the same issue, the thing is line-height is not calculated relative to the element's height but rather relative to its font-size. A solution I found to prevent the element from overlapping was to set it to display as `inline-block`. In your case:

```
.statement-text{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! One more quick question - is there a way to pull the bottom border in tighter? Border-spacing doesn't seem to have any effect. And, if I put a link above the "No!", it seems to overlap, and z-index seem to have no effect (the No link appears to block those below it).

Comment: @aronchick for the border spacing try setting a smaller line-height probably 80%, and I see what you mean that it overlaps other elements, that is strange, a fix would be to set overflow:hidden on the NO! link container or using z-index as you mentioned, just make sure to add an explicit `position:relative` rule to the element you need to adjust z-index

Comment: That is exactly what I needed! I'm surprised - I thought I tried inline-block with no success, but I must have done it on the container, rather than the text.